# How to search an entire WMI class instead of an instance?

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm working in c# and wondering if there is a way to check a full WMI class instead of getting an instance of the class. More specifically I'm looking at the Win32_ServerFeature class.

There is a huge list of all the IDs and their respective names and I was wondering if there was a way to get the name of a feature from its id. Right now, looking at an instance can only give me the name of the feature if it has been installed.

Is there a way to get the name of the feature from its id if it is NOT installed on the server?

Here is the list of Ids and Names that I am referring to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc280268(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [Win32_ServerFeature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc280268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `WMI` Class only exposes the installed features, so you are out of luck here, you best option is build a lockup table using the official documentation.